# solving a forcing differential equation with laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, differential, inverse-laplace, laplace-method

I'm working on a differential equations homework problem which I have to solve with laplace transforms:
$$y''-y'-2y=4x^2, y(0)=-1, y'(0)=1$$
And I'm having trouble specifically because of the forcing part, $4x^2$, which causes me to have two variables in the transformed equation $Y(s)$.

$$Y(s) = \frac{-s+(8/r^3)}{s^2-s-2}$$

Is this correct, and then how do I get $Y(s)$ into a form that I can take the inverse laplace of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be $8/s^3$. You either use $r$ or $s$ as a variable. If you are using $s$ as the variable for Laplace transform, you have $\mathcal L[f(x)]=\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-st}dt$, so that $\mathcal L[4x^2]=8/s^3$.